# Is there a way to pass in a variable dynamically into a toggle function without causing a looping error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a dynamic handler function that allows me to choose which state it is toggling true or false and pass this into a component

So far I get maximum depth exceeded

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    state1: false,
    state2: false,  
  }

  handleChange = (input) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({[input]: !prevState.input}));
  };

  render() {
   const { state1 } = this.state
   return (
     <DemoComp2 handleChange={this.handleChange} state1={state1}/>
   )
  }
}
```

Next component

```js
class DemoComp2 extends React.Component {
  render() {  
    const { state1, handleChange } = this.props;
    return(
      <button onClick={handleChange('state1')}>test</button>
      { state1 === true ? <p> true </p> : <p> false </p> }
    )
  }
}
```

Because in DemoComp2 onClick is calling handleChange() and not handleChange it infinitely loops.

But I need to pass state1 to the function with handleChange('state1') so it knows which state to toggle.

Is there another way of doing this that is as concise or do I need to break it out into separate functions?

Comment: You want `{...prevState, [input]: !prevState[input]}` and `onClick={() => handleChange('state1')}`

Comment: Rewrote it a bit. Live code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-snowflake-6brkb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here.

Your initial state is:

```
{
  state1: false,
  state2: false,
}
```

But when you update it, you're changing the format. You should use the spread operator to get the other parts of `prevState`:

```
handleChange = input => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      [input]: !prevState[input],
    }
  })
}
```

Secondly, `handleChange` isn't receiving the `state1` value - it's receiving the JS event. You need to call a function that calls `handleChange`:

```
<button onClick={() => handleChange('state1')}>test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happen here is that your onClick func is being called on each render instead only on onClick event. Just pass it an arrow func to avoid it.

onClick={() => handleChange(‘state1’)}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not think the code you shared works.

```
{ state === true ? <p> true </p> : <p> false </p> }
```

you have not declared `state` anywhere on Demo2 component

Second of all, you are executing the handleChange function right the way, instead of executing it when the button is clicked.

Solution

```
 class DemoComp2 extends React.Component {
  render() {  
    const { state1, handleChange } = this.props;
    return(
      <button onClick={() => handleChange('state1')}>test</button>
      { state1 === true ? <p> true </p> : <p> false </p> }
    )
  }
}
```